# populating 2 checkedlistbox from 2 different tables in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

From the title above, Im making a windows form in c# where in 2 of my checkedlistbox should populate the values from 2 tables in the database. However, when I tried to run the code, I always get this exception: "Cannot bind to the new value member".

below is my code. if you could find any errors/suggestions, feel free to comment. It would be a big help. thanks!

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            string connstring = ("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=021393;Database=postgres;");
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM data_condition", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt.TableName = "data_condition";
            da.Fill(dt);
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt;
            checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "conname";
            checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "conid";
            string[] condition = dt.Rows[0]["conname"].ToString().Split(',');

            NpgsqlCommand cmd2 = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM data_allergy", conn);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;        
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da2 = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            dt2.TableName = "data_allergy";
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            checkedListBox2.DataSource = dt2;
            checkedListBox2.DisplayMember = "allergyname";
            checkedListBox2.ValueMember = "allerygid";
            string[] allergy = dt2.Rows[0]["allergyname"].ToString().Split(',');
```

Comment: try giving column names in instead of * in your select query.

Comment: no use. been there. that's why i decided to use *